# Overloaded method value <> with alternatives w/ Play 2.1.1 and PlaySlick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm working on a case class for a program I'm writing in Scala with Play 2.1.1 and PlaySlick as a database mapper. The application concerns citations. We've got a citations table with >22 fields and as such we've narrowed down those down to the 22 that we *really* need to do most things. The code follows:

```
package models
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver._

case class Citation(citation_id: Int, pubtype: String, abs: String, keywords: String,      
                    doi: String, url: String, booktitle: String, chapter: String, edition: String, editor:       
                    String, translator: String, journal: String, month: String, number: String, pages: 
                    String, publisher: String, location: String, title: String, volume: String, year: 
                    String, raw: String, owner: String)

object Citations extends Table[Citation]("citations") {
  def citation_id = column[Int]("citation_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def pubtype = column[String]("pubtype")
  def abs = column[String]("abstract")
  def keywords = column[String]("keywords")
  def doi = column[String]("doi")
  def url = column[String]("url")
  def booktitle = column[String]("booktitle")
  def chapter = column[Int]("chapter")
  def edition = column[String]("edition")
  def editor = column[String]("editor")
  def translator = column[String]("translator")
  def journal = column[String]("journal")
  def month = column[Int]("month")
  def number = column[Int]("number")
  def pages = column[String]("pages")
  def publisher = column[String]("publisher")
  def location = column[String]("location")
  def title = column[String]("title")
  def volume = column[String]("volume")
  def year = column[String]("year")
  def raw = column[String]("raw")
  def owner = column[String]("owner") 

  def * = (citation_id ~ pubtype ~ abs ~ keywords ~ doi ~ url ~ booktitle ~ chapter ~   edition ~ editor ~ translator ~ journal ~ month ~ number ~ pages ~ publisher ~ location ~ title ~ volume ~ year ~ raw ~ owner).<>[Citation](Citation,Citation unapply _)
}
```

However we get this nasty error with the above code:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
overloaded method value <> with alternatives:   (f: (Int, String, String, String,     String, String, String, Int, String, String, String, String, Int, Int, String, String,    String, String, String, String, String, String) => models.Citation,g: models.Citation =>  Option[(Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, Int, String, String, String,  String, Int, Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String,  String)])scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[models.Citation,(Int, String, String, String,  String, String, String, Int, String, String, String, String, Int, Int, String, String,  String, String, String, String, String, String)] <and>   (f: ((Int, String, String, String,  String, String, String, Int, String, String, String, String, Int, Int, String, String,  String, String, String, String, String, String)) => models.Citation,g: models.Citation => Option[(Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, Int, String, String, String, String, Int, Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)])scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[models.Citation,(Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, Int, String, String, String, String, Int, Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)]  cannot be applied to   (models.Citation.type, models.Citation => Option[(Int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)])  Citations.scala /myapp/app/models   line 39 Scala Problem`
```

There's something wrong here with the default projection but I'm not sure what it is. We're right at the 22 arg limit but if we downsize it to 21 or 20 we still get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the type of *chapter*, *month*, and *number* fields. These are defined as **String** in your case class, but as **Int** in the table definition.